# Add integer ('how many years' from other table) to date column (date)

Tags: sql-server

I have to add customer.purchase_date to item.expire_date_years and get this result in customer.expire_date, for ex. 2017-01-16+2=2019-01-16

Tried this, not working

```
declare @year int   
set @year=
(select expire_date_years
from item)
declare @purchDate date   
set @purchDate=
(select purchase_date
from customer)
update customer
set expire_date=dateadd(yyyy,cast(@year as date),@purchDate)
```

**customer**

```
create table customer
(id int primary key identity(1,1),
name nvarchar(50),
purchase_date date,
expire_date date
)
insert into customer values('John','20170116')
```

**item**

```
create table item(
id int primary key identity(1,1),
name nvarchar(100),
expire_date_years int,
)

insert into item values('butter',2)
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close, just change your DATEADD call. Needs keyword "year" and takes the amount as an integer, don't cast it

```
update customer
set expire_date=DATEADD(YEAR, @year , @purchDate)
```

EDIT:
OK, the error you describe in the comments had nothing to do with how you're adding time to the date, it's because you're not focusing on a single item. So it should work with the example you have, but can't directly be extended to a larger system. Let's extend it a bit so it looks more like a real system - put a reference to an Item.ID in the table you want to update the expiration date for, then use that to look up the *single* expiration_years for that item. I converted to table variables because I can't get Fiddler to work today and I don't want schema changes in my database log, but it should look similar enough that you get the idea.

```
DECLARE @customer table 
(id int primary key identity(1,1),
name nvarchar(50), purchase_date date, PurchasedItem INT, expire_date date )

insert into @customer values ('John','2017-01-16', 1, NULL)
    , ('Alice','2017-02-22', 1, NULL)
    , ('John','2017-01-11', 2, NULL), ('Alice','2017-02-23', 2, NULL)

DECLARE @item table (id int, name nvarchar(100),expire_date_years int)

insert into @item values(1, 'butter',2), (2, 'Soup',3)
--Look at the tables before update, this feeds the below "UPDATE"
SELECT * FROM @customer as C INNER JOIN @item as I on C.PurchasedItem = I.id 

UPDATE @customer SET expire_date = DATEADD(YEAR, I.expire_date_years, purchase_date ) 
FROM @customer as C INNER JOIN @item as I on C.PurchasedItem = I.id 
--Now look at the result
SELECT * FROM @customer as C
```

Comment: I got error with set year and set purchDate :( Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.